# Anime/cartoon about a boy who wears red color clothes and could transform into some robot-type thing; includes a black robot with an F1-like car

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

The anime show has a boy who wears red-colored clothes and a bandanna on one hand. He could transform into some robot-type thing that had a bike. He has grills in his robot chest. There was also a man who could transform into a black robot who had a Formula 1 type of car. There was an episode where the guy with black armor in his automobile was moving in a loop in the power station mill type thing.

Comment: Hi there! That is a bit terse; could you please take a look at [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028) as well as [these ones on anime](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11874/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, when did you watch it?

Comment: I watched it a long time ago when I was a child. I was drawn into it for cool armor type things that can transform into a cool superbike and the protagonist was a teen and I watched it in space toon arabic in 2007-ish era

Comment: Nice to know. Please [edit] that into your question, as well as anything else you could remember, every detail, however minor it may seem, might lead to a successful ID :)

Comment: It was like in post apocalyptic era and i dont remember much but hero suit or armor looked liked kinda robocop but color was in red and the armor or suit's chest contain grill type structure and i dont know anything much

Comment: So, just to be clear, when the boy transformed into the robot, it had a bike? Or he could transform into a bike? And was the black robot the same one doing a loop in the power station mill thing?

Comment: At first he transforms into a robot and then that robot has a bike

Comment: Could it be Power Stone? There was a guy with red clothes in there that could transform into a robot-like thingy. I believe he also had a motorcycle, but I've not seen that show in over 15 years.